Why can't I use the row number on my where statement?
In the following CTE, outside it, I try to use the RowNum, but it is not recognized.
;with cte as(
select *
,min([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto) AS 'Min'
,max([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto) AS 'Max'
from Crypto
)
select [Crypto], [Date],
CASE (min([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto)) WHEN [Close] 
THEN (min([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto)) END as Min,
CASE (max([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto)) WHEN [Close] 
THEN (max([Close]) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto)) END as Max,
RowNum  = row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Date),Crypto, 'Min' ORDER BY YEAR(Date) desc)
from cte
where  ([Close] = Min  or [Close] = Max) and TowNum < 3

I'm not sure where is the problem.

RowNum vs TowNum ...

The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT list. I.e. it can't reference a column alias from the same query. You need a derived table, or another cte.

Nice! I looked into the derived table idea and found a solution!!!!!!!

You can't number the rows until you know which ones to keep.

where  ([Close] = Min  or [Close] = Max) and TowNum < 3

I think you misspelled 'RowNum' as 'TowNum' in the last line.
You are correct, it is misspelled, but it still does not work after I corrected it.

They did but even if they spelled it correctly it still couldn't be referenced in that WHERE
